# Signposts Ahead

Tags: yom-tov, travel, murder, yerushalayim-jerusalem, golus-exile

Why do we go out of our way to put up roadsigns for unintentional murderers ([Makkos 10a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=10&format=pdf)) while we do not for people going to Yerushalayim for Yomim Tovim (which is a Mitzva)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Brisker Rav** answers from a story in Navi, Elkanah (The Navi Shmuel's father) would be one of the few people to go up to Yerushlayim every year he took a different route in order that people find out that he is going and join him.The Brisker Rav said that is the answer to our question the unintentional murderer needed a quick way out with the least people finding out so that the siblings or other people who are allowed to take revenge not find out, while the person going up to Yerushalyim needed to do with asking people on the way which way to Jerusalem to encourage them to join in and to advertise this Mitzvah.